# Tkinter Widgets sometimes unresponsive after button click until I drag window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I have the following Tkinter program that lets users select file, upload it to YouTube, and add it to the desired playlist using the YouTube API:

```py
import os
import ntpath
import functools
from tkinter import *
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkButton, CTkCheckBox, CTkFrame, CTkSwitch
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox

from playlists import playlists
from formats import formats
from api import youtube


root = CTk()
root.title(string="YouTube Uploader")

frame = CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=10)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky=NSEW)

select = CTkButton(master=frame, text="Select Video")
select.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=150, pady=(20, 10), sticky=NSEW)

video = StringVar(master=frame, value=None)
def file(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if filename:
        video.set(value=filename)
        select.configure(fg_color="#1F6AA5")
        select.update()
        select.configure(state="disabled")

select.configure(command=file)

selected_playlists = []
def checkbox(playlist, variable):
    if variable.get() == "on":
        selected_playlists.append(playlist["id"])
    elif variable.get() == "off":
        selected_playlists.remove(playlist["id"])

check = {}
for index, dictionary in enumerate(playlists):
    variable = StringVar(master=frame, value=dictionary)
    check[index] = CTkCheckBox(master=frame, text=dictionary["name"], command=functools.partial(checkbox, playlist=dictionary, variable=variable), variable=variable, offvalue="off", onvalue="on")
    check[index].grid(row=(index + 1), column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky=W)

def upload_video():
    data = {}
    if video.get():
        for box in check.values():
            box.configure(state="disabled")
            box.update()
        data["video"] = video.get()
        data["playlists"] = selected_playlists
        try:
            youtube(data)
        except Exception as exception:
            messagebox.showerror(title=exception.__class__.__name__, message=f"Error in upload:\n\n{getattr(exception, 'message', repr(exception))}\n", icon="error")
        for box in check.values():
            box.configure(state="normal")
            box.deselect()
            box.update()
        select.configure(state="normal")
        select.update()
        video.set(value=None)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Video File Error", message="No video file selected, please select a video to upload and try again", icon="error")
        select.configure(fg_color="red")
        select.update()

upload = CTkButton(master=frame, text="Upload Video", command=upload_video)
upload.grid(row=(len(playlists) + 4), column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 20))

root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
root.mainloop()
```

I can't determine why, but sometimes the buttons / widgets become unresponsive after selecting the first widget upon running the program. The workaround I've noticed is that if you move the GUI window slightly on screen, they become responsive again.

What may be causing this?

Comment: Pardon me saying I was looking at your code but I couldn't seem to find the `playlists package`, can you add a link to the repo?